# Convert an ASCII string into its decimal equivilent - java/android

Tags: java, string, parsing, decimal, ascii

I'm trying to build an application that receives UDP string messages and then converts the string of characters in the packet to their decimal equivilents, i've tried a few methods and done some research but I cant seem to make any progress on this, i'm sure there must be a smart and easy way of doing this. Could anyone help me on this at all? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char ch = 'A';`

`int code = ch;`

Now you have the decimal equivalent in `code`.

If you have a `String` you should do this for each `char` from the `String`.

Comment: short and sweet.. :P +1

Comment: is it really that easy!? haha!

Comment: What if char most significant bit is set? Wouldn't that cause the integer to be negative?

Comment: The char is 16 bits. It is very unlikely that the msb is set.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the decimal equivalent of ascii like this,

```
int i='a';
System.out.println("i:="+i);
```